# Find the 2nd derivative of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\alpha}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\sqrt{2\alpha}|y-x|} f(y)dy$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $U_\alpha f(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\alpha}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\sqrt{2\alpha}|y-x|} f(y)dy$.

Then $\frac{d}{dx}U_\alpha f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\sqrt{2\alpha} |y-x|} sgn(y-x)f(y)dy=\int_x^\infty e^{-\sqrt{2\alpha}(y-x)}f(y)dy - \int_{-\infty}^x e^{-\sqrt{2\alpha}(x-y)}f(y)dy$.

However, I do not know how to derive the second derivative, which is given below. How do we get this? $f$ here is a continuous function vanishing at infinity.

$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}U_\alpha f(x)=\sqrt{2\alpha}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\sqrt{2\alpha}|y-x|}f(y)dy-2f(x)$.

Comment: The derivative of sgn is a δ-fctn, doubled, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

You can use the Leibniz rule on the integrals: $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)dt = f(b(x),t)b'(x)-f(a(x),t)a'(x) +\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t)dt. $$

Alternatively instead of splitting up the integral to get rid of the $sgn$ function you can use $$\frac{d}{dx}sgn(x) = 2\delta(x).$$